# How to write the Functor instance for this type?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm struggling with an exercise from [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/) (Chapter 16. Functor). Given the following, it expects me to define `fmap`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

newtype Flip f a b = 
   Flip (f b a) 
   deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype K a b = 
  K a

instance Functor (Flip K a) where
   fmap = undefined
```

In a previous exercise I've already done the following:

```
 data K a b =
   K a

 instance Functor (K a) where
   fmap f (K x) = K x
```

But for this `Flip a b`, I can't even understand how to get started, e.g. how to continue `fmap f Flip ...`.

I thought maybe before doing that I should also write a functor for the newtype `K a b`, similar to what I did `data K a b`:

```
instance Functor (K a) where
  fmap f (K x) = K x
```

But I can't understand how to proceed to the Functor instance for `Flip f a b`.

Any ideas, hints?

Comment: Finally I came up with something that type checks: `instance Functor (Flip K a) where
  fmap f (Flip (K x)) = Flip (K (f x))`. But right now I can't explain it to myself (don't even know whether it is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at your solution:

```
instance Functor (Flip K a) where
  fmap f (Flip (K a)) = Flip (K (f b))
```

What does `Flip (K a)` actually mean?

`K` is the constant functor, which you implemented correctly. It disregards the function `f` and always returns `K a`. But what actually happens behind the scenes is that the value `K a b` is transformed into `K a c`. Even though the function `f` was disregarded, the second type of `K` changed according to the type of `f`.

Now if we `Flip` `K`, we simply turn around the arguments:

```
Flip (K a b) == K b a
```

Instead of having a constant value and ignoring the function, we have a changing value and a constant "ignored" type. Looking at the implementation with explicit type signatures we get:

```
instance Functor (Flip K a) where
  fmap :: (b -> c) -> Flip K a b -> Flip K a c -- or:
  fmap :: (b -> c) -> K b a -> K c a
  fmap f (Flip (K a)) = Flip (K (f b))
```

As you already concluded, the only possible implementation is the one above.

You can actually see the use cases of a `Constant` functor in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951758/foldable-monoid-and-monad/) question.