# Foldable, Monoid and Monad

Tags: haskell, category-theory, foldable

Consider the following signature of `foldMap`

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

This is very similar to "bind", just with the arguments swapped:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

It seems to me that there therefore must be some sort of relationship between `Foldable`, `Monoid` and `Monad`, but I can't find it in the superclasses. Presumably I can transform one or two of these into the other but I'm not sure how.

Could that relationship be detailed?

Comment: FYI, `concatMap'` is `foldMap` from the `Foldable` class in `Data.Foldable`.

Comment: Ah silly me question simplified.

Answer (score 26):

#### `Monoid` and `Monad`

Wow, this is actually one of the rare times we can use the quote:

> A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, [...]

Let's start with a monoid. A monoid in the category `Set` of sets is a set of elements `m` with an empty element `mempty` and an associative function `mappend` to combine elements such that

```
mempty `mappend` x == x -- for any x
x `mappend` mempty == x -- for any x
-- and
a `mappend` (b `mappend` c) == (a `mappend` b) `mappend` c -- for all a, b, c
```

Note that a monoid is not limited to sets, there also exist monoids in the category `Cat` of categories (monads) and so on. Basically anytime you have an associative binary operation and an identity for it.

Now a monad, which is a "monoid in the category of endofunctors" has following properties:

It's an endofunctor, that means it has type `* -> *` in the Category `Hask` of Haskell types.

Now, to go further you must know a little bit of category theory I will try to explain here: Given two functors `F` and `G`, there exists a natural transformation from `F` to `G` iff there exists a function `α` such that every `F a` can be mapped to a `G a`. `α` can be many-to-one, but it has to map every element of `F a`. Roughly said, a natural transformation is a function between functors.

Now in category theory, there can be many functors between two categories. Ina  simplified view it can be said that we don't even care about which functors map from where to where, we only care about the natural transformations between them.

Coming back to monad, we can now see that a "monoid in the category of endofunctors" must posess two natural transformations. Let's call our monad endofunctor `M`:

A natural transformation from the identity (endo)functor to the monad:

```
η :: 1 -> M -- this is return
```

And a natural transformation from the conposition of two monads and produce a third one:

```
μ :: M × M -> M
```

Since `×` is the composition of functors, we can (roughly speaking) also write:

```
μ :: m a × m a -> m a
μ :: (m × m) a -> m a
μ :: m (m a) -> m a -- join in Haskell
```

Satisfying these laws:

```
μ . M μ == μ . μ M
μ . M η == μ . η M
```

So, a monad is a special case of a monoid in the category of endofunctors. You can't write a monoid instance for monad in normal Haskell, since Haskell's notion of composition is too weak (I think; This is because functions are restricted to `Hask` and it's weaker than `Cat`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-issue) for more information.

#### What about `Foldable`?

Now as for `Foldable`: there exist definitions of `fold`s using a custom binary function to combine the elements. Now you could of course supply any function to combine elements, or you could use an existing concept of combining elements, the monoid. Again, please note that this monoid restricted to the set monoid, *not* the catorical definition of monoid.

Since the monoid's `mappend` is associative, `foldl` and `foldr` yield the same result, which is why the folding of monoids can be reduced to `fold :: Monoid m, Foldable t => t m -> m`. This is an obvious connection between monoid and foldable.

@danidiaz already pointed out the connection between `Applicative`, `Monoid` and `Foldable` using the `Const` functor `Const a b = Const a`, whose applicative instance requires the first parameter of `Const` to be a monoid (no `pure` without `mempty` (disregarding `undefined`)).

Comparing monad and foldable is a bit of a stretch in my opinion, since monad is more powerful than foldable in the sense that foldable can only accumulate a list's values according to a mapping function, but the monad bind can structurally alter the context (`a -> m b`).

Comment: "Wow, this is actually one of the rare times" - *giggles nervously*

Answer (score 10):

**Summary**: `(>>=)` and `traverse` look similar because they both are arrow mappings of functors, while `foldMap` is (almost) a specialised `traverse`.

Before we begin, there is one bit of terminology to explain. Consider `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

A Haskell `Functor` is a functor from the **Hask** category (the category with Haskell functions as arrows) to itself. In category theory terms, we say that the (specialised) `fmap` is the *arrow mapping* of this functor, as it is the part of the functor that takes arrows to arrows. (For the sake of completeness: a functor consists of an arrow mapping plus an *object mapping*. In this case, the objects are Haskell types, and so the object mapping takes types to types -- more specifically, the object mapping of a `Functor` is its type constructor.)

We will also want to keep in mind the category and functor laws:

```
-- Category laws for Hask:
f . id = id
id . f = f
h . (g . f) = (h . g) . f

-- Functor laws for a Haskell Functor:
fmap id = id
fmap (g . f) = fmap g . fmap f
```

In what follows, we will work with categories other than **Hask**, and functors which are not `Functor`s. In such cases, we will replace `id` and `(.)` by the appropriate identity and composition, `fmap` by the appropriate arrow mapping and, in one case, `=` by an appropriate equality of arrows.

### (=<<)

To begin with the more familiar part of the answer, for a given monad `m` the `a -> m b` functions (also known as Kleisli arrows) form a category (the Kleisli category of `m`), with `return` as identity and `(<=<)` as composition. The three category laws, in this case, are just [the monad laws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051842/2751851):

```
f <=< return = f
return <=< f = f
h <=<  (g <=<  f) = (h <=<  g) <=<  f
```

Now, your asked about flipped bind:

```
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)
```

It turns out that `(=<<)` is the arrow mapping of a functor from the Kleisli category of `m` to **Hask**. The functor laws applied to `(=<<)` amount to two of the monad laws:

```
return =<< x = x -- right unit
(g <=< f) =<< x = g =<< (f =<< x) -- associativity
```

### traverse

Next, we need a detour through `Traversable` (a sketch of a proof of the results in this section is provided at the end of the answer). First, we note that the `a -> f b` functions for *all* applicative functors `f` taken at once (as opposed to one at each time, as when specifying a Kleisli category) form a category, with `Identity` as identity and `Compose . fmap g . f` as composition. For that to work, we also have to adopt a more relaxed equality of arrows, which ignores the `Identity` and `Compose` boilerplate (which is only necessary because I am writing this in pseudo-Haskell, as opposed to proper mathematical notation). More precisely, we will consider that that any two functions that can be interconverted using any composition of the [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) and [`Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) isomorphisms as equal arrows (or, in other words, we will not distinguish between `a` and `Identity a`, nor between `f (g a)` and `Compose f g a`).

Let's call that category the "traversable category" (as I cannot think of a better name right now). In concrete Haskell terms, an arrow in this category is a function which adds an extra layer of `Applicative` context "below" any previous existing layers. Now, consider `traverse`:

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> (t a -> f (t b))
```

Given a choice of traversable container, `traverse` is the arrow mapping of a functor from the "traversable category" to itself. The functor laws for it amount to the traversable laws.

In short, both `(=<<)` and `traverse` are analogues of `fmap` for functors involving categories other than **Hask**, and so it is not surprising that their types are a bit similar to each other.

### foldMap

We still have to explain what all of that has to do with `foldMap`. The answer is that `foldMap` can be recovered from `traverse` (cf. [danidiaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39952209/2751851) -- it uses `traverse_`, but as the applicative functor is `Const m` the result is essentially the same):

```
-- cf. Data.Traversable
foldMapDefault :: (Traversable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> (t a -> m)
foldMapDefault f = getConst . traverse (Const . f)
```

Thanks to the `const`/`getConst` isomorphism, this is clearly equivalent to:

```
foldMapDefault' :: (Traversable t, Monoid m)
                => (a -> Const m b) -> (t a -> Const m (t b))
foldMapDefault' f = traverse f
```

Which is just `traverse` specialised to the `Monoid m => Const m` applicative functors. Even though `Traversable` is not `Foldable` and [`foldMapDefault`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:foldMapDefault) is not `foldMap`, this provides a decent justification for why the type of `foldMap` resembles that of `traverse` and, transitively, that of `(=<<)`.

As a final observation, note that the arrows of the "traversable category" with applicative functor `Const m` for some `Monoid` `m` do *not* form a subcategory, as there is no identity unless `Identity` is among the possible choices of applicative functor. That probably means there is nothing else of interest to say about `foldMap` from the perspective of this answer. The only single choice of applicative functor that gives a subcategory is `Identity`, which is not at all surprising, given how a traversal with `Identity` amounts to `fmap` on the container.

### Appendix

Here is a rough sketch of the derivation of the `traverse` result, yanked from my notes from several months ago with minimal editing. `~` means "equal up to (some relevant) isomorphism".

```
-- Identity and composition for the "traversable category".
idT = Identity
g .*. f = Compose . fmap g . f

-- Category laws: right identity
f .*. idT ~ f
f .*. idT
Compose . fmap f . idT
Compose . fmap f . Identity
Compose . Identity . f
f -- using getIdentity . getCompose 

-- Category laws: left identity
idT .*. f ~ f
idT .*. f
Compose . fmap Identity . f
f -- using fmap getIdentity . getCompose

-- Category laws: associativity
h .*. (g .*. f) ~ (h .*. g) .*. f
h .*. (g .*. f) -- LHS
h .*. (Compose . fmap g . f)
Compose . fmap h . (Compose . fmap g . f)
Compose . Compose . fmap (fmap h) . fmap g . f
(h .*. g) .*. f -- RHS
(Compose . fmap h . g) .*. f
Compose . fmap (Compose . fmap h . g) . f
Compose . fmap (Compose . fmap h) . fmap g . f
Compose . fmap Compose . fmap (fmap h) . fmap g . f
-- using Compose . Compose . fmap getCompose . getCompose
Compose . Compose . fmap (fmap h) . fmap g . f -- RHS ~ LHS
```

```
-- Functor laws for traverse: identity
traverse idT ~ idT
traverse Identity ~ Identity -- i.e. the identity law of Traversable

-- Functor laws for traverse: composition
traverse (g .*. f) ~ traverse g .*. traverse f
traverse (Compose . fmap g . f) ~ Compose . fmap (traverse g) . traverse f 
-- i.e. the composition law of Traversable
```

Answer (score 7):

When a container is `Foldable`, there is a relationship between `foldMap` and `Applicative` (which is a superclass of `Monad`).

`Foldable` has a function called [`traverse_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_), with signature:

```
traverse_ :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()
```

One possible `Applicative` is [`Constant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Constant.html). To be an Applicative, it requires the "accumulator" parameter to be a `Monoid`:

```
newtype Constant a b = Constant { getConstant :: a } -- no b value at the term level!

Monoid a => Applicative (Constant a)
```

for example:

```
gchi> Constant (Sum 1) <*> Constant (Sum 2) :: Constant (Sum Int) whatever
Constant (Sum {getSum = 3})
```

We can define `foldMap` in terms of `traverse_` and `Constant` this way:

```
foldMap' :: (Monoid m, Foldable t) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldMap' f = getConstant . traverse_ (Constant . f)
```

We use `traverse_` to go through the container, accumulating values with `Constant`, and then we use `getConstant` to get rid of the newtype.